# Wagtail: How to validate m2m inline model?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a custom form inheriting from `WagtailAdminPageForm` and I want to validate an m2m model field (`ClusterableModel`). Right now I am using the `clean()` method on my form class.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    my_field_total_sum = 0    
    for form in self.formsets['my_field'].forms:

        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_form_data = form.clean()
            my_field_total_sum += cleaned_form_data.get('my_value')

            if total_sum > 100:
                form.add_error('my_value', 'More then 100 is not allowed')

    return cleaned_data
```

This works fine until I add and/or remove some inline panels in the admin interface and save my page as a draft and try to validate again. Because `self.formsets['my_field'].forms` still contains already removed forms and never gets reset to the actual amount of inline panels in the admin.

So, is it possible to (re-)set `self.formsets['my_field'].forms` to the actual amount inline panels visible in the admin interface? Or should I validate elsewhere anyways?

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I found the answer. Checking for the "DELETE" key in a  `form`s `cleaned_data` dict is the key. So my `clean` method from above needs to look like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    my_field_total_sum = 0    
    for form in self.formsets['my_field'].forms:

        # simply check, if "DELETE" is not true
        if form.is_valid() and not form.cleaned_data.get("DELETE"): 
            cleaned_form_data = form.clean()
            my_field_total_sum += cleaned_form_data.get('my_value')

    # this check needs to be outside the loop ;-)
    if my_field_total_sum > 100:
        form.add_error('my_value', 'More then 100 is not allowed')

    return cleaned_data
```